# Google Script (spreadsheet) Quotas issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't understand how it works.

What is situation:
I have a Spreadsheet with Script which contains few functions. There are 3 triggers

- on Edit (30-40 times per day - 2 seconds each run)
- Hourly (2-3 seconds each run)
- Minutely

this Minutely function worked all the time (55 seconds per run and them new one) and it caused many errors like
"Excessive use of the machine time per day by the service"

I edited it and it run 2 seconds and finishes. Also I did it working once 10 minutes.
While I didn't it my script worked 1 time per 5-6 runs. So as I understand Google calculated daily limit for last 24 hours - every minute. And once 5-6 minutes it gave script possibility to run

Now it works 1 time per 2-3 runs. So lets say

- 12:11 - Runs without problem
- 12:21 - error "Excessive use of the machine time per day by the service"
- 12:31 - error "Excessive use of the machine time per day by the service"
- 12:41 - Runs without problem

etc..
I can't understand how Google calculates this restriction of daily overage.
In Helo I found that summary script run time must be <=60 minutes
Lets say
40*2 + 24*2 + 6*24*2 = 194*2 = approx 400 seconds = 5 minutes...

Why it continue give me these errors? Already half a day after I changed it.

Comment: Try changing your notifications on the triggers to immediate so that you can get any error notiification more often throughout the day.  Also keep in mind that just because some code ran for 3 seconds one time doesn't mean that it always finishes in 3 seconds.

Comment: I have found the machine time error to be very unpredictable. I spent some time with Google support on it, and they couldn't offer any insight. I use this script to keep track of how much time each of my triggers takes to execute: https://medium.com/@dkodr/how-to-keep-track-of-google-apps-scripts-total-execution-time-c46e9d1dfdef - and do my best to optimize